# Are there any differences between Linux and Cygwin which might explain behaviour of Bash regex test?

Tags: regex, bash, cygwin

I'm writing a Bash script to process folders matching a particular regex pattern which during development within a Linux is working as expected.

```
regex="^([Pp]age\s*)*([1-9][0-9]*.*)"
if [[ "$dir" =~ $regex ]]; then
  # do stuff here
fi

# matches
# 'Page 1 james'
# 'Page2 darren'
# '49'

# does not match
# 'NOT THIS Page 1 james'
# 'Page 007'
# 'randomfolder'
```

However, the same script within a Cygwin environment fails.

Both environments use the same Bash version (4.3.46)

Both environments provide the expected results for the regex using grep.

I'm no regex master so am unsure if I'm missing something with the regex, or if there's a perculiarity of Cygwin which explains why this is failing.

Additional information:
The folders are on a NAS drive, accessed via NFS in Linux, and Samba from Windows. $LANG is `en_GB.UTF-8` on all three.

Comment: `\s` is provided as an "enhanced" regular expression. `[[:space:]]` should be identical, but more portable. Not posting as an answer because I can't explain why `bash` and `grep`, which presumably use the same underlying library, would behave differently.

Comment: Thanks, using `[[:space:]]` does seem to improve the script, but will have to check properly tomorrow.

Comment: may be difference in LANG settings ?

Comment: No difference in LANG settings. Using [[:space:]] instead of \s has fully resolved the problem, but can't say why. Perhaps a bug?